# After I removed action bar it leaves a blank space

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest

[image: BottomNavigation also I'm getting blank space, don't know what is that reason][image: I used NoActionBar to remove my action bar, but leaves the space there]

I don't know how to solve this. Kindly please help me to solve this problem.

> themes.xml

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: how did you remove it? make sure you remove Toolbar from activity xml too if you had included that.

Comment: How Can I remove toolbar for activity xml

Comment: Bottom navigation also I'm getting space

Comment: share code (xml) of that activity if you can. that way it is easy to help

Comment: I don't know how to share XML code in comment

Comment: you can update your question activity layout. but before you do that, search Toolbar  in android project and it can point where it is used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that you have a toolbar in your layout file, check your layout file

Comment: No I don't have toolbar in layout file